# Could not resolve SDK Path while install capybara-webkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sdk, rubygems, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am trying to install capybara-webkit gem on my macbook (sierra 10.12.6) but I still have some problems. I installed Xcode, gt, I tried almost every solution but I think I made it even worse :(

Now the error is "Could not resolve SDK Path for 'macosx'". Full message is on link down.

Can someone help me? :-/

[full error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioahI.png)

Comment: I also had capybara-webkit problem and no solution yet. Bet Good answer.

Comment: I think I have solution. But not sure I can say everything what I done, because I did a looot of things around. Buuut - try instal xcode ( [here](https://www.embarcadero.com/starthere/xe5/mobdevsetup/ios/en/installing_the_commandline_tools.html) ), accept licence od xcode ( [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175069/how-to-accept-xcode-license) ) and then gt ( [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#homebrew) ). Then I finally could type gem install capybara-webkit without error!! :O

Comment: Thank you, @Viola, so capybara-webkit belongs to qt right?

Comment: @artgb I do not understand much, but after two days of fighting, I can say yes. You need to have xcode command line tools and gt installed